# Automatic mock instantiation in a Spring JUnit test

Tags: spring, junit4, mockito

I have a Spring XML bean definition that I want to write integration tests for. The XML bean definition is part of a larger application context where several such files are included using `<import>`. Inside the definition, I reference several beans that are coming from other files.

For my integration test I would like to instantiate the definition standalone and use Mockito mocks for all other beans. Until now, I am using something like this:

*FooIntegrationTest.java*

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class FooIntegrationTest {
  @Autowired private ClassUnderTest underTest;
  @Autowired private MockedClass mock;

  @Test
  public void testFoo() {
  }
}
```

*FooIntegrationTest-context.xml*

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <import resource="part-to-test.xml" />

  <bean id="mockedClassReferencedByName" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock" c:classToMock="SomeMockedClass" />
  <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock" c:classToMock="OtherMockedClassReferencedByType" />
  <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock" c:classToMock="MockedClass" />
  ...
</beans>
```

I would like to automate the rather tedious mocking section: Ideally, I would like to have all beans that are not found in the application context to be mocked automatically. The `part-to-test.xml` uses `@Autowired` as well as beans that are set by using name references. I only use XML bean definition files, and neither use `@Configuration` classes nor `@Component` annotations.

I have looked into how to use a custom context loader in `@ContextConfiguration(loader=...)`, but I have not yet found an appropriate extension point for doing so. Sprinockito does not seem to adress this problem.

Is there some other project out there that already solves this problem? If not, where would I extend Spring to create the mocks automatically?

Comment: Have you tried the Mockito @InjectMocks annotation?  In what way does it fall short of your requirement?

Comment: @DavidWallace `@InjectMocks` works extremely well for unit tests, i.e. testing one particular class where the test is using mocked objects. However, I would like to mock all objects that are referenced in a Spring bean definition. This means that I need to populate the Spring application context with (possbily named) mocks - I am not aware how `@InjectMocks` helps for doing this.

Comment: OK, I'll think about this some more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [short article with a code example](https://dzone.com/articles/automatically-inject-mocks). A `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` implementation generates a mock object for each lacking bean definition. The generation part is done with a `MocksFactory`, here is [an example for such a factory](http://hg.randompage.org/java/src/407e78aa08a0/projects/bookmarking/backend/spring/src/test/java/org/randompage/bookmarking/backend/testUtils/MocksFactory.java).

Comment: This answer was the right starting point for tackling the problem: Using a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` makes it possible to introspect the bean definitions for missing beans. I extended the code example to also take care of beans that are injected using setters, but such an extension is rather trivial.

Comment: The second link is dead. R.I.P. old article

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone is still interested in this question, I have extended the code in the article mentioned by Yves Martin with inheritance, support for @Inject, etc... and created a Github project here: https://github.com/rinoto/spring-auto-mock